# Why is this website copying Stackoverflow's content?

Tags: discussion, copyright

Here's the original stackoverflow.com question:

[ImportXML function format data in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094656/importxml-function-format-data-in-spreadsheet)

and there's a website which copied my question & answer and posted it as someone else:

http://www.forums.srvinfo.com/xml/importxml-function-format-data-in-spreadsheet_569872

What the hell? Is it copyright legal and all? It's not me posting there lol and definitely it's not their "expert" answering that question...

Comment: Well I'm just concerned about Not my nickname and no credit for answerer & Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yup, so it's in breach of CC-by-SA, hence the dupe.